# What should I do or instead getActivity()

Tags: android, android-activity

I want send value to onFinishEditDialog  but i don't know how to do it.
Please help me or Do you have another method.

```
public  String strhashtag;
public interface EditNameDialogListener {
    void onFinishEditDialog(String inputText);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.hashtaglayout);
    Intent hashtag = getIntent();
    strhashtag = hashtag.getStringExtra("hashtag");

    Button btnendhashtag = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnendhashtag);


    btnendhashtag.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditNameDialogListener activity = (EditNameDialogListener) getActivity();
            activity.onFinishEditDialog(strhashtag);
            finish();
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: It error getActivity(); can't use

Comment: Is this code inside a `Fragment` or `Activity` class? `setContentView()` and `finish()` implies an `Activity`, but `getActivity()` implies a `Fragment`

Comment: Activity class , What should I use?

Comment: @WachirawitRukamatoo If this code is inside an `Activity` class, then where are you trying to send your information to via your `interface`? If you want to start a new `Activity` and pass this information on a button press, you should use the `Intent.putExtra()` method on your `startActivity()` `Intent`.

Answer (score 0):

Add GreenRobot's EventBus to Gradle like so:

```
compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
```

Then, in EditNameDialogListener activity, instantiate an instance of it

```
private EventBus bus;

onCreate {

    bus = EventBus.getDefault();
    bus.register(this);
}

onDestroy {

    bus.unregister(this);

}
```

Create a FinishEditDialog class

```
public class FinishEventDialog() {
    // COnstructor, getters and setters for custom data you want to send over
}
```

In EditNameDialogListener activity provide this method:

```
public void onEvent(FinishEditDialogEvent event) {
    // do whatever you want here, extract data from the event
}
```

in your current activity, post an Event to any registered listeners:

```
onClick {

    EventBus.getDefault().post(new FinishEditDialogEvent()); 
}
```